# Integrate AWS Cognito to MEAN Stack

Tags: passport.js, mean-stack, amazon-cognito

I have a starter level MEAN app with angular v4. There is no Authentication mechanism built in yet no passport nothing. I want to use AWS cognito for Authentication (Sign In/UP). Do I need passport for this purpose or Cognito is enough by itself. I am not sure about the steps to take for Integrating Cognito to MEAN. Do I need to start by integrating Passport to MEAN and then Cognito. Or only Cognito. I couldn't find an example for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [passport-cognito](https://github.com/kndt84/passport-cognito), it integrates cognito with passport with passport strategies.

Now you only need to integrate passportjs with your MEAN stack. There is no sample example that illustrates passport-cognito with passportjs though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to add passport for authenticating user from third party authentication provider.
And after user login, passport returns the accesstoken which is should be given to AWS cognito,then cognito verifies the access token by contacting with third party authentication provider.
In this way AWS cognito and passport works to get authentication done using third party authentication provider.